# Angry birds arms

Tags: minifigures

Is it possible to attach the [Angry Birds arms](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0759&name=Arm%20Angry%20Birds%20with%20Feathers&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Part%5D#T=C&C=11) to a regular minifigure, or is the attachment pin different?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Angry Bird arm on a minifig, and vice versa]

I got hold of an Angry Bird, and can confirm the arms are totally interoperable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any Angry Birds components, but comparing these pictures:

[image]

[image]

they look at least similar in construction and scale, so I'd bet they are compatible.